# Building and enormous tree and being bugged with a stackoverflow error

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, stack-overflow, large-data

im working on a project and in my project I have to build a tree. The tree will have around 64000 leaves. Unfortunetly I keep running into a stackoverflow error and I have no idea what to do at this point. Did i write my recursive method wrong or is there a workaround for the error?
Code in constructor:

```
for(int i = 0; i < wordHolder.size(); i++) {
            add(i);
        }
```

Add method:

```
public void add(int i){
        mainTreeNode = treeSetup(mainTreeNode, 0, wordHolder.get(i), countHolder.get(i));
    }
```

and the recursive method that sets up the tree:

```
private TreeNode treeSetup(TreeNode node, int letterCount, String s, List<Integer> i) {
        if(letterCount == 26) {
            letterCount = 0;
        }
        if(node == null) {
            node = new TreeNode(s,i);
        } else if (i.get(letterCount) >= node.test.get(letterCount)) {
            node.right = treeSetup(node.right, letterCount++, s, i);
        } else if(i.get(letterCount) < node.test.get(letterCount)) {
            node.left = treeSetup(node.left, letterCount++, s, i);
        }
        return node;
    }
```

The node is a standard node that contains 2 data structures (a list and a string). The idea is that node is put into a spot based on what the list contains. Also, each level in the tree is checked based on a different value from the list (like a KD tree), hence the letterCount variable. the problem seems to be in the

```
node.right = treeSetup(node.right, letterCount++, s, i);`
```

line but changes based on whichever "if statement" has the "=" sign. If i remove the "=" sign from both "if statements" the problem goes away but i lose a huge amount of accuracy.` Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is Java? You didn't specify but it looks like it. Other than best practice issues one thing I see is 2 else if's, if you must do if's should be if if if else for Java. However a case switch might be better for this study.

The constructor should have for loops in it. A constructor should be a blueprint, that you call to build your instance of an object. It just has all the references and information to give you a skeleton. Then you use other methods to give it some flesh.

Personally first thing I would try is to make the Treenode treeSetup more like an initializer for the instance of the constructor. Let it take parameters and pass those to the object instance that will need them to set its uniqueness. Put the for loop inside the void method, build your Params to pass to the Treenode method inside the void, then pass all of the information to it, and let it set all the goodies for you.

for the setting of the nodes itself there are better ways to do this, but quick and dirty

```
if (letterCount == 26) {
letterCount = 0;
}
if (node != null) {
if (letterCount %2 == 0) {
do left stuff
} else {
do right stuff
}
}
return
```

else if works but honestly if you can find a way to use an enum or switch case, much more modern. 
Another thing you should be looking at, is you are using 2 data types in a strange way, there is already a perfect item for 2 data types containing a key and a value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: But theres noway for me to fix that stackoverflow problem?

Comment: Also, i have to use a kd tree, the problem is much larger and kd tree is the way to solve it (its similarity based)